# Accessing hbase (using JPA, JDO, any other way) in Java EE applications inside a container

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jdo, hbase, datanucleus

How to access hbase (using JPA, JDO, or any other way) in Java EE applications inside a container (e.g. glassfish, jboss etc)? How to make connection pool inside the container? I have tried datanucleus, but its documentation and examples are not fullfilling this requirement. Also datanucleus layer makes hbase access slower than hbase' own client API, and I couldn't find a way to make connection pool in it (to hbase). Kindly provide any links for studying in depth about it.

Comment: http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

As already answered in comment default client is acceptable in many cases (see [package summary](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/package-summary.html)). Simple use cases are creating/managing tables with [HBaseAdmin](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html) and scanning/inserting with [HTable](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html). It's required to put `hbase-site.xml` into resources or specify connection properties manually.

Also there is another client - [Asynchbase](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/asynchbase), which allows to work with HBase in async way. Entry point here is `HBaseClient` class (it doesn't use conf files, specify properties in your code).